# Dynamic IP range

Tags: networking, ip, isp

With a dynamic IP address, each time I start up my router I get a new IP address by my ISP.
But is there any sort of range where that IP is taken from? I mean, after X new requests, is there a chance to get the same IP?

Comment: Both of the answers to your questions entirely depends on your ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about a public IP, or the IP which is assigned to the WAN side of your router? The two are different.

The public IP is the one which is returned to you by visiting sites like whatismyipaddress.com, and the like. This is how you are identified to a site you visit which does not belong to your ISP. However, the WAN side of your router is generally not assigned a public IP, but another private IP, generally in the range 10.0.0.0/8; this is because your ISP is NATting his many subscribers through a (hopefully for him) much smaller number of public IP addresses which he had to buy. The process is identical to that which occurs in a home: there is only one external IP, even though there may be tens of IP addresses inside your home, yet communications aren't garbled up.

Since you did not pay for a public IP, you will be assigned as a matter of course (so you do not get for free what you are expected to pay for) different WAN-side IPs, and different public IPs. I do not believe for a moment your ISP is so kind to reserve for you always the same address, it would be like telling those who are paying for their static IPs that they are wasting their money.

So now your question becomes quite reasonable: how often should I expect to obtain the same IP? For the public IP, it is likely you should expect to re-obtain the same one, in the average, after N new IP assignments, where N is the number of public IP adddresses your IP bought from IANA. In the case of the WAN-side IPs, that would be every 2^24~~ 4,000,000 times. This however neglects the fact that often ISPs create VLANs inside their private address pool (10.0.0.0/8), i.e., different, non-communicating subnets. This is done of course the reserve different classes of service to different subscription plans, plus to accommodate service lines, plus occasionally government-reserved lines, and so on. In this
case your probability to get the same address is somewhat reduced, but it depends strongly on the policy and the number of subscribers of each individual ISP.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the range that your ISP is using.  The chances of getting the same IP will be on how many IP's the ISP have in their range.  For example: with 5 IP's in a range your chances is better of sometime getting the same IP.  ISP's usually have quite large IP ranges. Your chance will then be 1 in x amount of IP's in the range.  If you want a static IP, you may want to contact your ISP and ask if you may obtain one.

Answer (score 0):

[DHCP](http://whatismyipaddress.com/dhcp) is the protocol used to provide dynamic IPs to clients.  DHCP is given a range of IP addresses called a DHCP [scope](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_scope_and_super_scope).

Another feature of DHCP servers is that they will try to provide the same IP address to the same client if possible.  There is no guarantee that you will get the same address, but if its available, it will give it to the machine that leased it before.  It is strange that you find yourself getting a different IP address every time you restart your router, I would suspect your ISP is over subscribed, or for some odd reason they disabled the feature that tries to reserve an IP for the same customer.

Comment: Why should it be strange? It is even normal, I would say.