# Do the last 5 digits from an IP Change?

Tags: ip

I was wondering if you have a dynamic IP, or a Static IP and you change your ip by unplugging modem, will your last 5 digits from IP be the same or would they change? Also are you the only one with these 5 digits or can your neighbors and other people from your ISP have them?

EXMP: xx.xx.241.28

and yes my ip does look like that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic IP range](http://superuser.com/questions/664824/dynamic-ip-range)

Comment: Any device you set up with a static local IP address should retain the local address regardless of public IP changes.

Comment: @root this is about a public ip, not a local ip, thus it doesn't apply.

Comment: If its a static address then its going to be static.  If you have a dynamic ip adress then it will change when and only when your ISP determines it should change.

Comment: @LPCHip It's worth noting.

Comment: well apperantly people can check if you are the same person who connected to a server even if you change your IP adress, because and i quote "We can check the last 3 digits of your IP". i thought some people might also have the same last 3 numbers of my IP but everything else different. I wasnt sure.

Answer (score 1):

### Address allocation

Your ISP's equipment will allocate IP version 4 addresses from a pool. It is likely that this pool contains one or more continuous ranges of addresses. These will be allocated more or less randomly.

Usually the servers try to allocate the same address as was used last time but this is not always feasible with small pools and a large turnover of customers.

If your ISP has provided a static IP-address (some ISPs charge extra for this, some don't) you should always gett the same public IP-address allocated to your router. For some ISPs this depends on unique authentication credentials configured in your router (as I discovered when my ISP replaced a router killed by lightning), other ISPs might simply associate the static IP-address with the WAN-side MAC address of the router.

So yes, if you have a Dynamic IP-address, as most people probably do, your neighbor might today have the IP-address that you were using yesterday. Or vice-versa.

### IP V4 Addresses

You talk about "last 5 digits" but each of the four numeric parts of an IP V4 address can have from one to three digits (0-255). For example:

1.1.1.1
 10.0.17.33
 192.168.1.1
 192.168.1.250
 192.168.250.187

So really you are referring to the last two octets which may be represented as two to six decimal digits (actually two lots of one to three digit numbers)

The address is really a 32-bit number in the range 0 to 4294967295. It is just presented in "dotted quad" form with four decimal octets for historical reasons (look up "classful network" if interested)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but not necessarily.

An ISP that has many ip addresses may choose to always give you a new ip upon reconnecting. They can also reserve your IP address and try giving you that ip address unless you are not connected and they need to assign someone an IP address and yours happen to be free.

Also, it does matter how big the scope of the ISP is and how they configured their DHCP servers. They may keep you in a pool of 254 values so only the last digit changes.